# Looping through files in directory

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, types

I want to loop through all files in given path to directory and echo the type of each file.

So far I managed to do these:

```
for file in `ls $path`
do
    if [[ -f "$file" ]];
    then
        echo "file"
    fi

    if [[ -d "$file" ]];
    then
        echo "DIR"
    fi 
done
```

but I don't get anything evendough I have two directories inside a path?

Comment: Don't parse the output from `ls`. Just use `for file in "$path"/*` if `$path` is a directory or `"$path"*` if it is a file prefix.

Comment: I get your expected output using your code.

Comment: See [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: Looping Trough? Pertussis is very contagious, I'd stay away completely.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid parsing `ls` output, a better solution is (using `glob`) :

```
path=/tmp/foobar
cd "$path"
for file in *
do

    if [[ -f "$file" ]]
    then
        echo "FILE $file"
    fi

    if [[ -d "$file" ]]
    then
        echo "DIR $file"
    fi 
done
```

Comment: thanks! How could I just add one more detail and that is a name of file before type in echo?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear I just want the last part from file, what lies after last /

Comment: I have one more little question. Is there anything specific to write at the end of recursive function because I was trying to write this for all subdiretories for a given depth.

Comment: example: i have two maps(dir1 and dir2) in the first depth with this subdiretories:
>dir1
>>dir1.1
>>dir1.2
>>>dir1.2.1

,

>dir2
>>dir2.1
>>dir2.2

if the depth is given 2 i would like to get:

>dir1
>>dir1.1
>>dir1.2

and

>dir2
>>dir2.1
>>dir2.2

but I only get:

>dir1
>>dir1.1
>>dir1.2

Comment: You could do `for file in **` with `bash4` it's recursive. Add before processing `shopt -s globstar` to be sure to enable this feature

Answer (score 0):

`ls` doesn't display `$path` itself. You can add it back manually:

```
for file in `ls -- "$path"/`
do
    file="$path/file"  # New code line.
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]
    then
        echo "file"
    fi
    if [[ -d "$file" ]]
    then
        echo "DIR"
    fi 
done
```

However, please consider Etan Reisner's comment, and get rid of `ls`, because it's most probably unnecessary in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this:

```
find  your/path  -maxdepth 1  -type f -exec file {} \;
```

If you need to recursively dig into sub-folders, just remove `-maxdepth 1` option like this:

```
find  your/path  -type f -exec file {} \;
```

If you need to also print the folder name, and its type (type == "Directory", of course), just remove the `-type f` option like this:

```
find  your/path  -exec file {} \;
```